# What's the recommended memory efficient way to perform mass property update?

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4j DB with more than 30 million nodes. I'm wondering what might be the most efficient (regarding memory and speed) approach to do a bulk update of a returning pattern within a node property using only the Cypher Shell.

e.g.: having a node with the label USER with a property name of the type String like:

```
'Peter_Test'
```

If I want to get rid of all the underscores in a bulk update what's the best way to achieve this without having to select each of the 30 million nodes in a single transaction, update the content and write it back to the same property?

A selection of all USER nodes upfront and a following UNWIND for each entry within the selection plus an update would definitely run into memory issues.

Any advice to perform such a task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use apoc procedure apoc.periodic.iterate for this ,

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate( "MATCH (o:Order) WHERE o.date > '2016-10-13' RETURN o", "MATCH (o)-[:HAS_ITEM]->(i) WITH o, sum(i.value) as value SET o.value = value", {batchSize:100})
```

This is example in the documentation. Where you return the nodes to be updated in first query and do the update in second query.here ,you won't load all 30 million nodes at once..you can configure it using batch size .

Check out the documentation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/periodic-execution/)